# Move projects between two SVN repository

Tags: svn, backup-restoration

Our main svn repository went down due to a hardware failer 2 weeks back so I had to set up temporary local svn in an Ubuntu box to keep the development running with recovered working copies from local pcs.

After some time I manage to recover the old remote server and fix the issue we were having. additionally, manage to spin old svn server up and running.

so now I want to commit local server folders to the remote server,

So the only option I know is to check out a projects' working copies from the remote server and overwrite with latest and commit( from the temporary server), which seems working fine but this way I'm going to lose history for last 2 weeks.

So my question is is there any other way that I can salvage the last 2 weeks history?

Comment: Have you considered migrating to a version control system where this wouldn't be a problem such as Git or Mercurial?

Comment: that a plan for the future but with time being svn is very useful since we have lots of non that techy end users that use source control( eg artists. ).

Answer (score 1):

*More or less* good way of joining these two repos is **dumps**

1. Create dump of 2-weeks repo with `svnadmin dump` ([RTFM](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html)) or `svnrdump dump` ([RTFM](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnrdump.c.dump.html)), using method, which you are allowed to use (svnadmin require local access to **FS or repo**, svnrdump - only ability to **read repository**)
2. Restore dumps from the above into "big" repository, using corresponding commands of svnadmin or svnrdump

Power way

With "DVCS of choice" "pull" data from both SVN-repos (both 1-st class modern DVCSes - Mercurial and Git - can do it, in slightly different ways), rebase part if it's needed (i.e DAG is broken and history is torn), "push" to repaired repo. I wrote "COMMAND", because real commands are *different* in mentioned SCMs. I'll suggest don't delete DVCS's repo after all, but use it as additional backup with mirroring changes in SVN-repo to it all time later